# Matlab: Find row indice of first occurrence for each column of matrix (without using loops)

Tags: matlab, matrix

For each column of a matrix A consisting of '0' and '1', I would like to find the column indices of the first occurrence of '1' if exists. For example, if A is defined as:

```
 A=[0 0 0 0;
 0 0 0 1;
 0 0 0 0;
 0 0 0 1;
 1 0 0 0;
 0 1 0 1;
 1 1 0 0]
```

then the result would be:

```
b=[5 6 2]
```

I'm searching for a solution without any 'for' or 'while' loops.

One solution I came up with:

```
 [b,~]=find(cumsum(cumsum(A))==1)
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is shorter than anything posted and it's a one liner. 
Code:

```
[~,idx] = max(A(:,sum(A)>0));
```

Output:

```
idx =

     5     6     2
```

EDIT: Just realized you can do:

```
[~,idx] = max(A(:,any(A)))
```

Comment: this doesnot tell which column does the element in idx belongs to

Answer (score 5):

@Nacer - nice answer. By default [a,m,c] = unique(J) returns the vector `m` to index the **last** occurrence of each unique value in J. Use `[~,m] = unique(J, 'first');` instead.

```
[I,J] = find(A==1);
[~,m] = unique(J, 'first');
I(m)

ans =    
     5
     6
     2
```